# MongoDB transactions spanning multiple web requests

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions, atomic

I'm trying to implement a **MongoDB** transactions API service over HTTP using Go
where the client sends a request to: `/db/transaction/begin`
to acquire a Transaction ID
in order to bind all subsequent transaction-related CRUD operations API requests with that Transaction ID
and finally the client either sends a request to `/db/transaction/{transaction_id}/commit`
or `/db/transaction/{transaction_id}/rollback`
(something somewhat similar to Firestore Transaction)

I was able to implement this kind of behavior with **ArangoDB** since it's Go Driver allows me to set the Transaction ID of each CRUD operation (https://godoc.org/github.com/arangodb/go-driver#WithTransactionID)

but unfortunately i couldn't achieve this with the official MongoDB Go Driver

am i missing something?
Is there a workaround or any custom implementation which could help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution is to store (buffer) the operations in your application and submit them all together to MongoDB when the commit endpoint runs.

Technically you can manually manage transaction lifecycle in your application and implement transactions spanning web requests but this is 1) going to be quite awkward and 2) you are going to lose the various transient error handling that the driver does for you in the withTransaction API.

To do this:

- Familiarize yourself with [sessions specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/sessions/driver-sessions.rst)
- Familiarize yourself with [transactions specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst)
- Read the [convenient tx api spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions-convenient-api/transactions-convenient-api.rst) so that you know what you *won't* be getting for free, if your customer asks why you are exposing errors that drivers don't
- Review the code in your driver implementing these specifications
- Implement enough of session and transaction management for your requirements in your application

Might be easier to fork & patch the driver but this obviously has other issues resulting from your codebase diverging from the official driver codebase.

Comment: this would work fine had the client only wants to do batched writes, but the problem arises when the client needs to fetch a document first to be checked against some client-side domain-logic rules before doing any writes (postgres: select for update... ).  the transaction-related CRUD ops needs to be stateless and separate on server-side except for a unique transaction ID to group them into an atomic operation at committing.

Comment: When I think about it some more you'll need to reimplement sessions and transactions handling in your application since the driver probably won't allow you to set session id externally either. Doable but  a lot of work.