# Mongodb C# Transaction on multiple Controller

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am implementing a project where there are 5 controllers in one solution and all of them are getting called independently. On click of save, I am calling these 5 API but now the problem is how can i manage transaction. If first call is made, I am starting a transaction, if any of the calls failed I need to rollback, how can I do it.

Comment: you'll need one controller which can run all the operations together. You can't do a transaction by calling them all independently, it needs to be done with server-side code. (You can of course also keep the code which does each operation separately, if that's sometimes useful, there's nothing to stop you having both versions.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Stateless Transactions with Go Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660527/mongodb-stateless-transactions-with-go-driver)